# Returning the matched element from a $in query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I have several documents that follow this structure:

```
{
  "queue-type": <integer>,
  "participants": [{
     "id": <integer>,
     "level": <level>,
     "flags": <integer>
  }]
}
```

And there is an multikey index on `participants.id`.

During the code, there is a find query, as follows: `db.queues.find({"participants.id": {"$in": [2, 3, 4]}})`, which gives the following as result:

```
{"queue-type": 1, "participants": [{"id": 1, "level": 10, "flags":4},{"id": 2, "level": 10, "flags":8}]}
{"queue-type": 25, "participants": [{"id": 5, "level": 10, "flags":4},{"id": 15, "level": 10, "flags":8},{"id": 4, "level": 10, "flags":8}]}
```

Is there any way to also retrieve the the element that was used to match on the query? Something like:

```
{"queue-type": 1, "_matched": 2, "participants": [{"id": 1, "level": 10, "flags":4},{"id": 2, "level": 10, "flags":8}]}
{"queue-type": 25, "_matched": 4, "participants": [{"id": 5, "level": 10, "flags":4},{"id": 15, "level": 10, "flags":8},{"id": 4, "level": 10, "flags":8}]}
```

PS: I'm trying to avoid looping through the `[2, 3, 4]` and the `participants` array, since they are way bigger.

Examples:
queues

```
{"queue-type": 1, "participants": [{"id": 1, "level": 10, "flags":4},{"id": 2, "level": 10, "flags":8}]}
{"queue-type": 2, "participants": [{"id": 3, "level": 10, "flags":0}]}
{"queue-type": 3, "participants": [{"id": 4, "level": 10, "flags":4},{"id": 5, "level": 10, "flags":8}]}
{"queue-type": 4, "participants": [{"id": 7, "level": 10, "flags":4},{"id": 8, "level": 10, "flags":8},{"id": 9, "level": 10, "flags":8}]}
```

The result I wish to retrieve:

```
db.queues.find({"participants.id": {"$in": [2]}});
{"queue-type": 1, "_matched": 2, "participants": [{"id": 1, "level": 10, "flags":4},{"id": 2, "level": 10, "flags":8}]}
```

Note the "_matched" element is the same as the 'participant.id' given on the search query

Another example:

```
db.queues.find({"participants.id": {"$in": [2, 3, 6]}});
{"queue-type": 1, "_matched": 2, "participants": [{"id": 1, "level": 10, "flags":4},{"id": 2, "level": 10, "flags":8}]}
{"queue-type": 2, "_matched": 3, "participants": [{"id": 3, "level": 10, "flags":0}]}
```

Multiple matches example:

```
db.queues.find({"participants.id": {"$in": [1, 2, 3]}});
{"queue-type": 1, "_matched": 1, "participants": [{"id": 1, "level": 10, "flags":4},{"id": 2, "level": 10, "flags":8}]}
{"queue-type": 1, "_matched": 2, "participants": [{"id": 1, "level": 10, "flags":4},{"id": 2, "level": 10, "flags":8}]}
{"queue-type": 2, "_matched": 3, "participants": [{"id": 3, "level": 10, "flags":0}]}
```

---

A not good solution is to simply copy the 'participants' data ('participants-cpy') and then run:

```
db.queues.find({"participants-cpy.id": {"$in": [2]}}, {"participants-cpy.$":1, "participants":1, "_id": 1, "queue-type":1})
```

which could be used to retrieve the element used to 'match' the query, but that would generate duplicated data - which is pretty bad :p

Comment: What do you mean by `the element that was used to match on the query` ?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear here.
On the query, I always pass a list (on the example [2, 3, 4]), but most of the times just one element of the list will be matched successfully. Going to update the post to try to make it clear.

Comment: I understood what you want. You can try using `aggregate` and `$group`, which is the way to get what you want.

Comment: @titi23 it is not so easy as you need pass query parameter to compare what was matched - easiest way will be use `$filter` and return only matched documents or in simple query `$elemMatch` [more here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)

Comment: As the question says, he needs to know matched element count for each of the values in the array `{"$in": [2, 3, 4]}`. So I thought `$group` will be the solution to get the counts. @profesor79

Comment: @titi23 - that's seems legit, but we are talking about parametrised query , which is not straightforward as passing parameters in sql world... Looking forward for your query proposal as this is interesting problem.

Comment: Added a possible solution, but not the optimal one, maybe it could help? :p

Comment: @AdrianoMartins what if there are multiple matches in one record? If there are objects with `participants.id` as `2` and `3` in one record? what will be `_matched` in this case?

Comment: @titi23 as example I've used a single element, but it could also be a list holding all the matches. Will update the question to change `_matched` to list

Comment: @AdrianoMartins You want all the objects of the `participants` array or it's okay to get just the matched objects from the array?

Comment: Must retrieve all the elements on the participants array. While editing, figured out the `_matched` element must be a unique value, or a list with a single value, due to the fact that the query does not limit to documents with all the elements present, so it would run for `2` and for `3`, returning a duplicated find result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular [`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) query will not work here. You need to use the aggregation framework. In your pipeline you need to select only those documents that match your query criteria using the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline operator.

The next and last stage in the pipeline is the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage where you use add the new field "_matched" to your documents. If you think about it, you will realize that the new field nothing other than an array that contains the elements that appear in your "partcipantsId" array/list and in all the "id" from the "participants" field in your document.

To get that value you simply perform a set intersection operation on the participantsId array and the array of "id" from "participants" using the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and the [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) operator. Note that the resulted array contains only unique entries because `$setIntersection` filters out duplicates.

```python
participantsId = [1, 2, 3]
db.queues.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "participants.id": { "$in": participantsId } } }, 
    { "$project": {
        "_matched": {
            "$setIntersection": [
                { "$map": { 
                    "input": "$participants", 
                    "as": "p", 
                    "in": "$$p.id"
                }}, 
                participantsId
            ]
        }, 
        "queue-type": 1, 
        "participants": 1
    }}
])
```